# Can anyone help me with fixing a VBS script on Windows 10 that displays a warning/MsgBox on low battery?

Tags: windows, vbscript

What I'm trying to do is write a script that creates a message box/popup when my computer's battery falls to 20%. I want the message box to appear only once—it shouldn't show up again after I click "OK" unless I charge my computer and let it drain to 20% again.

The problem is that the code I have causes message boxes to appear every few minutes while my battery is below 20%. My code is below:

```
set oLocator = CreateObject("WbemScripting.SWbemLocator")
set oServices = oLocator.ConnectServer(".","root\wmi")
set oResults = oServices.ExecQuery("select * from batteryfullchargedcapacity")
 
for each oResult in oResults
    iFull = oResult.FullChargedCapacity
next

while (1) 
    set oResults = oServices.ExecQuery("select * from batterystatus")
    for each oResult in oResults
        iRemaining = oResult.RemainingCapacity
        bCharging = oResult.Charging
    next
    iPercent = Round((iRemaining / iFull) * 100)
    
    if iRemaining and not bCharging and (iPercent < 21) and (iPercent > 10) Then msgbox "Your battery power is low (" & iPercent & "%). If you need to continue using your computer, either plug in your computer, or shut it down and then change the battery.",vbInformation, "Your battery is running low."
    wscript.sleep 30000 ' 5 minutes
wend
```

I'm very new to VBScript (and programming in general), so I'm not really sure how to fix this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to have a flag for example a variable called iShow. It starts with value 1 (message can popup), after you click OK, iShow will be zero (don't show again). The next time this flag will have value 1 is when the batery is more than 21%, so when it fall again to less 21% the message can popup again but just once. Here is the code:

```
set oLocator = CreateObject("WbemScripting.SWbemLocator")
set oServices = oLocator.ConnectServer(".","root\wmi")
set oResults = oServices.ExecQuery("select * from batteryfullchargedcapacity")

for each oResult in oResults
    iFull = oResult.FullChargedCapacity
next

Dim iShow
iShow=1

while (1) 
    set oResults = oServices.ExecQuery("select * from batterystatus")
    for each oResult in oResults
        iRemaining = oResult.RemainingCapacity
        bCharging = oResult.Charging
    next
    iPercent = Round((iRemaining / iFull) * 100)
    
    if (iPercent>21) then iShow=1
    if (iShow=1) and not bCharging and (iPercent < 21) Then
         msgbox "Your battery power is low (" & iPercent & "%). If you need to continue using your computer, either plug in your computer, or shut it down and then change the battery.",vbInformation, "Your battery is running low."
         iShow=0
    end if
    wscript.sleep 30000 ' 5 minutes
wend
```

Comment: I can't vote up because my account isn't established enough, but I just want to confirm that this works like a charm. Thank you!